# UI gets distorted when dismissing modal view controller in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, modalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

```
modalViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"transparentFullViewController"];

listViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 333);
CGPoint center=modalViewController.view.center;
listViewController.view.center=center;

[modalViewController addChildViewController:listViewController];
[modalViewController.view addSubview:listViewController.view];
listViewController.view.center = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view.center;
```

this is how i present the modal view controller

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and this is how it is dismissed

```
[modalViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

when I dismiss the modalViewController in iOS 7, it works fine and return to the 2nd screen shot
but when I dismiss it in iOS 8.0, then the view becomes distorted as shown in 1st screen shot

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.[image: distorted view][image: normal view]

Answer (score 1):

you are setting properties of parent on which modal need to pops, that's why it does not work,

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

but it should be like , as here setting modal controller presentaion style, etc

```
modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

Comment: Rather than just saying "you're wrong", it'd be more constructive to explain why the OP's code fails and why yours works.

Answer (score -1):

In iOS 8 try to use another presentation style:

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```